# laravel display data on same page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm working on php laravel framework. After click button I want to echo my php variable on same page

echo $somevariable; in same page

How can I modify this script?

```
 <script >$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
    var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
    var ajaxurl = '/Ds/showoutputs',
    data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        // Response div goes here.

         alert("action performed successfully");
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Should `$somevariable` go where it currently says `action performed successfully`?

Comment: actually I want to give the result in some div not like pop up.

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript code is **inside a view** and therefore get's processed by PHP you can simply do this:

```
<script>
    var somevariable = "{{ $somevariable }}";
</script>
```

Now you can use `somevariable` anywhere in your javascript code.

You could also inject it directly:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
    var ajaxurl = '/Ds/showoutputs',
    data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        var div = $('<div></div>');

        div.text("{{ $somevariable }}");

        alert("action performed successfully");
    });
});
```